# List all git local branches that start with string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, git-bash

I want to list all local branches (eventually delete but for safety's sake...) that ONLY begin with abc. The thing is that this *kind of* works. But if no branch starts with "abc" then it lists **ALL** of the branches. which is what I don't want to end up doing (deleting all my local branches)

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/abc\* | xargs git branch --list
```

Comment: Why are you using `xargs` here at all? Is the output from `for-each-ref` not what you want already?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what xargs does. Would removing it help?

Comment: Actually removing it makes it not work at all

Comment: I meant remove the entire `| xargs git branch --list` bit entirely. `xargs` transforms standard input into command line arguments for the command it runs. My point in this case was that the output from `for-each-ref` is *already* the list of branches. Why are you handing that to `git branch` at all? (Yes, removing just the word `xargs` is going to not do anything useful. It will always just give you the full list since `git branch` isn't reading standard input.)

Comment: gotchya, but now i want to delete them instead of just list them

Comment: True, you just need the `-r`/`--no-run-if-empty` to avoid the command being run without any arguments.

Comment: git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/abc\* -r / --no-run-if-empty

error: unknown switch 'r'

Comment: Sorry, that's an argument to `xargs` and the argument is *either* `-r` **or** `--no-run-if-empty`.

Comment: hm, still just lists it.

git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/abc\* | xargs -r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to tell `xargs` not to execute its command if it has no input.

You do that with the `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` argument.

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/abc\* | xargs --no-run-if-empty git branch --list
```

Answer (score 8):

To list all branches that begin with "abc":

```sh
git branch --list "abc*"
```

So if you want to delete them, then run the following:

```sh
git branch --list "abc*" | xargs --no-run-if-empty git branch --delete
```

You can append the `--force` flag to the command above if you want to live dangerously.